# Extract first non empty values from unrelated tags in XML using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

Suppose I have this XML

```
`<root> 
<numbers>
 <first>
    <elementone></elementone>
    <elementtwo></elementtwo>
 </first>
</numbers>  
<first>
    <elementone>100</elementone>
    <elementtwo>200</elementtwo>
</first>
</root>`
```

I would like to extract the first occurrence of non-empty value from . In this case, I would like to see 100 as the result. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, giving us a little more context (what are you doing this in?) and telling us what you have tried will help us get you better answers, as well as making it more relevant when people stumble upon it in google.

Answer (score 2):

Try: `//root//node()[string-length(normalize-space(text()))>0][1]`

Comment: Thanks. Your xpath gives the first non-empty from <numbers>, but it doesn't look at the elements that are outside <numbers>. Meaning there is a <first><elementone>100</elementone><elementtwo>200</elementtwo></first> outside <numbers> in the above XML

Answer (score 2):

/*/*/*/*[normalize-space()][1]

This will check in nodes under the fourth branch of your XML doc structure for a non empty content and return the first occurence